# Does ROW_NUMBER queried data require to fetch the entire result set?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write query that's not using offset (because as I just have learnt offset fetches all data which causes performance overhead). with ROW_NUMBER window function. For instance:

```
SELECT id
FROM(
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
FROM users) sq
WHERE rn > 1000
```

Does it require all rows to be fetched as it would be with `offset 1000`? I mean, does it make a sense to use such query instead of

```
SELECT if
FROM users
OFFSET 1000
```

? Do I get performance improvement on large amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) docs. Window functions operate on the result set, after the fetch:

> Window functions are permitted only in the SELECT list and the ORDER
>   BY clause of the query. They are forbidden elsewhere, such as in GROUP
>   BY, HAVING and WHERE clauses. This is because they logically execute
>   after the processing of those clauses. Also, window functions execute
>   after regular aggregate functions. This means it is valid to include
>   an aggregate function call in the arguments of a window function, but
>   not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense to use the `row_number()` query?  Well, it produces the same result set.  However, the query basically has to assign `row_number()` to *all* the rows in order to find the ones that meet the requirement.

The second query, however, is lacking an `order by`.  When using `offset`, you should have an `order by`:

```
SELECT id
FROM users u
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 1000
```

I would imagine that this is more efficient than using `row_number()`, but actual timings would demonstrate that.